# Why surface charges work different in polarizing than in steady current?

Tags: electric-fields

A metallic conductor crossed by an electric field is polarized and a certain surface charge is distributed in order to cancel the applied field. Similarly, in a DC circuit made up of a battery and a high resistivity metallic conductor, when the switch is open, surface charges appear to cancel the electric field of the battery inside the conductors.
However, in a closed DC circuit, the surface charges work in order to complement the battery field so that the resulting field inside the conductors is adequate for there to be a stationary current.
Why in the first two cases the surface charges Work to cancel the field and in the last one it works to redirects it?
[image]

The e-field from a battery has not rectangular field lines, rather it resembles that of a dipole, so there must be something generating other e-fields that together with the battery e-field give a resulting e-field that has, at all points of the circuit, the conductor's direction (This is, and not other, the e-field needed to have a steady current). That "something" is certain surface charges that emerge along the conductor, sometimes + and sometimes -.

In the case that the circuit were open at one point, (it is known that the e-field inside a metallic conductor in equilibrium is zero) the e-field at all points inside the conductor would be zero, but the battery e-field is still there. What counteracts the battery e-field are the e-fields generated by surface charges that emerge along the conductor.

The question is: why in one case do charges appear helping to achieve a steady current and in another do charges appear for the opposite: to reach equilibrium by canceling the battery e-field?.

I must be missing something....

Comment: "when the switch is open, surface charges appear to cancel the electric field of the battery inside the conductors." What conductors are you talking about?

Comment: For simplicity I mean a DC battery and a single conductor that closes the circuit on said battery, the conductor has a certain uniform resistance to avoid a short circuit. I added a picture.